# How to keep flex items at top of the container when height is increased

Tags: css, flexbox

Im working on an accordion drop down and using flex box to align everything on the page. However, I am running into an issue where item are being centered vertically, even though I want them to stay on top.

You can see what I mean in this code pen, I'd like the items to stay on top and only push down one side of the dropdown where clicked.

https://codepen.io/maciekmat/pen/QWLqred

```
.loh-faq-container{
    display: flex;
    margin: 2em 0 4em;
    align-items: flex-start;
    align-self: flex-start;
}

.loh-faq-wrap{
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 45%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    align-self: flex-start;
}
```

To my understanding, align-items: flex-start; should work, especially when applying to the child flexbox, but I could very well be wrong. Whats going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be your `margin: auto;` on `.loh-faq-wrap` that is doing this.

Change from:

```
.loh-faq-wrap {
    margin: auto;
}
```

To this:

```
.loh-faq-wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Auto margins can be used for centering things. So I would recommend [reading up on that](https://learnlayout.com/margin-auto.html).

Comment: Oh wow, I dont know why I thought the margin:auto only works on aligning something horizontally. Thank you for your help